# Remove space from regular expression

Tags: regex

I do not want to show error when adding space. While using this regular expression, when adding space, shows error. How can I solve this?

```
return /^[A-Za-z\‘“:(),.$#!?=-_/\{}<>%^*]+$/.test(value);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you only want to allow typographic closing quotes (single/double) and not ASCII quotes `'` and `"`?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean that you want to allow spaces within `value`, right?

Then simply add a space to the character class. Make sure that the dash is never between two characters in the class, unless you want to specify a range (as you probably meant to do in `A-Z` but not in `=-_`). Also, this regex contains an error because you didn't escape the `/`:

```
return /^[- A-Za-z‘“:(),.$#!?=_\/{}<>%^*]+$/.test(value);
```

Comment: Great, but please also take a look at my comment to your question.

Comment: +1 I got to admit that I didn't think about the range thing and I missed the slash error. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Add spaces using `\s` to the regex:

```
/^[-\sA-Za-z\‘“:(),.$#!?=_\/\{}<>%^*]+$/
```

As @Tim suggested below, `/` should be escaped and the `-` should not come between two characters for which it will define a range. Answer was updated respectfully.

Second, as was noted in the comments below, it's worth mentioning that `\s` matches all types of spaces (tabs, newlines etc) which is even more general than what the OP asked for

Comment: Depending on what OP is doing, `\s` might or might not solve the problem, the latter because `\s` also matches characters other than a space.

Comment: Furthermore, this solution leaves several errors in the original regex unfixed.

Comment: @Jerry it's good to mention that `\s` matches *all* types of spaces (tabs, newlines etc) which is even more general than what the OP asked for. That said, I don't think it should be a problem.

Comment: @TimPietzcker fixing an additional error is great - thank you for doing that. That said, downvoting an answer for *not* doing that sounds absurd to me. Oh well...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I just commented...and I will upvote when the errors are fixed because the information about `\s` is useful.

Comment: Then the second part of my previous comment is not to you :) @TimPietzcker

Comment: @TimPietzcker done. I got humbled & educated simultaneously - thanks for that!